# How to get real braces in ttfont, in latex

Tags: latex

In latex, you can type `\verb|{|` and get a real brace in a typewriter font. But if you type `{\tt \{ }`, you get a sans-serif replacement. In code:

```
\verb|{|    % nice, real brace.
{\tt \{ }   % hideous fake brace.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OMS/lmtt/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `OMS/cmsy/m/n' instead
(Font)              for symbol `textbraceleft' on input line 3.
```

How do you get the real, monospaced brace in a `tt` environment? (I can't just nest `verb`, because I need to change its color as well.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the T1 font encoding with

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

Comment: Nice.  I like your answer better. +1.

Comment: @Alok, this might be cleaner, but your answer is a helpful alternative too, esp. if there are any incompatibilities with the `fontenc` package etc. I'd recommend returning it...

Answer (score 5):

You can try `{\tt {\char '173}}`:

```
\newcommand{\lcb}{{\tt {\char '173}}}
```

See [this](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/msg/87a64886fd60bd1a).  Seems to work for me.

Comment: For the record, the right curly brace is character 175. So this is the complement: `newcommand{\rcb}{{\tt {\char '175}}}`